# Server Free Memory

Tags: linux, memory, redhat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Free / Cached / Available memory on Linux](https://serverfault.com/questions/394951/free-cached-available-memory-on-linux)

My Redhat server shows the following:

```
free -m 
============= 
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached 
Mem:          8113       8078        35          0        171       6491   
-/+ buffers/cache:       1415       6698   
Swap:         8189         59       8130
```

Is 35 mega of free memory considered critical on a production server ?

Answer (score 4):

No! you got 6698 MB as file-/buffercache used, this is good! if a program/service needs more ram the file cache ("cached") is getting reduced and the program get the freed RAM.
a good explanation why and how it works here:
http://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Answer (score 3):

Unused memory is utilized for disk caching.

Linux rarely shows a high `free` in number in the Mem column, and hence that metric is a bit misleading in determining RAM constraints.